# mergExt - tap to focus and explosure in mergAVCamCreate

Tags: video-capture, livecode

I did't find a function to do this, I ask just to be sure: in mergAV, mergAVCamCreate is possible activate Tap to focus and hold to explosure in video?

Answer (score 0):

Single tap to autofocus and double tap to continuously autofocus is supported at the moment... at least the code is in there... I would need to look into long press for exposure.